# A intro of the story where the main character talking through a microphone

Tags: introduction

I plan to change my prologue into where the character is talking his story to another dimension's audience. The problem is, I don't know how to write the first step properly.

Is it [Recording], [Mic on], or is it just something else? (His storytelling is on TV, so I don't know how do I make it into a recording of sorts.)

For example: [Recording] "Hi, my name is ______" or [Mic on] "Hi, my name is ______"

And no, it is not screenwriting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Hello? Is this thing on? Okay, good. Uh, where to start. Ooh, how about-"

If it's not screenwriting, this is probably the best strategy for opening. It quickly sets up that there is a recording device of some sort with possible tech difficulties (like a microphone).

Although this exact wording implies somebody else is there, which I think there is in your case, but if you don't want that you can try:

> "I think this is working, right? Test test. Okay, good, it works for once. Now then-"

Again, it shows there is a recording device with possible tech difficulties.